# How to reprogram Vim's :help command to open in specified location

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim 7.4.459 on Arch Linux. Some time ago (days) the :help command split the window in two halves (top and bottom) and always opened the help file in the bottom half. Now, this command opens the help in the top half (why?).

How to configure Vim so that the :help command opened the help in the bottom half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when a new window is created depends on the `splitbelow` and `splitright` options (among others). Both options have *always* been off by default, which gives you the "opening help in the top half" behaviour. That behaviour has been the *standard* behaviour for years.

Turn them on to get the desired behaviour:

```
set splitbelow
set splitright
```

As for what happened…

you probably had these settings in a system-level `vimrc` that was wiped out during the upgrade process. Distribution maintainers often put default values in such files to make them available to all users and new users often put *their own* settings there out of ignorance.